# How do I fix the fact that I'm working on the wrong branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch

Ok so I meant to be working on a branch called `directory-layout`, but it turns out that I am working on a branch called `master`. This is a problem.

I have not yet performed `git add .` nor `git commit -m "I've made a horrendus mistake I'm sorry"`

What do I do to add my changes to another (or new) branch and why?

Comment: First, if you mean to create that as a new branch starting from the current commit, just use `git checkout -b directory-layout` and you're all good. If not: well, I know this might *seem* dangerous, but it's quite safe: whether `directory-layout` is an existing branch, or is to be made from an existing remote-tracking branch, *try* just running `git checkout directory-layout`. If that works, you're good to go. If not, use one of the backup strategies. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that branch is a new one, you can simply create it:

```
git checkout -b anewbranch
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

But if that branch is an old one, you can [cherry-pick the commit instead](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick):

- add, and commit
- switch to the old branch
- git cherry-pick master

Then reset master to its previous commit

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard @~1
```

Another approach would be to use [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), then switch to the old branch and stash apply.

Comment: The point is: I prefer committing first: that way I don't lose anything. Then I can switch that commit around.

Comment: Interesting. So `cherry-pick` lets me transfer the `HEAD` of one branch to another?

Comment: @RobTruxal cherry-pick let you apply any commit (or set of commits) to another branch. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would try doing.

```
  git checkout -b <newbranch>
```